# Cancel index creation on SQL Azure (init by portal)

Tags: azure-sql-database

Azure portal has a neat (apparently) feature where it monitors the use to which a SQLAzure database is being put and suggests indexes that may improve performance

I accepted a recent recommendation without noticing that the index creation includes nearly every other column (including an NVARCHAR(MAX) column) of a truly humongous table..

..that create index op has been running for an hour now, and I'd dearly love to cancel it because it's clowning performance of several live sites. Portal offers no way (help docs say "An executing operation cannot be canceled" and SQL scripts i run on the DB looking for other running queries/active sessions turn up no results

Is there any way to halting this index creation? While I approve of the notion of creating this particular index in as far as the column suggested SHOULD be indexed, I don't think there's much benefit in practically recreating the entire table into the index thanks to all the INCLUDING columns; for the thousand rows out of millions that the index might return, and the infrequent hit, i'm happy to take the punch on the nose of doing a lookup of related info, rather than including it in the index (duplicating the table)

Comment: does it show up in sys.dm_exec_requests dmv

Comment: @thegameiswar sadly not! :/

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, at this point it's not supported to cancel the recommendation that went into executing state. We take special care to not give the recommendations that will result in creating a large index so your example definitely is interesting for us to investigate.

Can you please publish a tweet mentioning the @AzureSupport and asking this question? This way Microsoft Support team will create a task that I can take over.

Comment: Hi vvasic, I'm afraid I don't have a twitter account. Is there any other way you would like me to get in touch with them? I can send you an email with my subscription ID if you like